# Installing python packages in Ironpython

Tags: python, ironpython, ironpython-studio

I have made few functions in Pycharms using the following packages:

- `Urllib.requests`
- `Numpy`

However, when I used these functions inside a code that I wrote in Ironpython (used in order to make a GUI), I recieved an exception that there are no such modules.

How can I install packages used in function?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Installing modules in IronPython should be as easy as:

```
ipy -X:Frames -m pip install urllib3
```

But sometimes IronPython is a pain.